# Why is the following function returning null ArrayList?

Tags: arrays, list, kotlin, arraylist

I have even used List but still, I get null pointer but if I use livedata it updates successfully inside the for a loop. It doesn't return null. Why is it only list or Arraylist which returns null

```
  fun List(): ArrayList<Bank> {
    val banklist = ArrayList<Bank>()
    val reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        .child("groups")
        .child(group.group_id)
        .child("financials")
        .child("cash")
        .child("bank")
    reference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {

        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

        }

        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {

            for (singleSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                Log.d(
                    "Data", "banks found: "
                            + singleSnapshot.value
                )
                val bank = singleSnapshot.getValue(Bank::class.java)
                banklist.add(bank!!)

               bankListLivedata.value = banklist //updates perfectly

            }


            Log.d(
                "Data", "banksList1 ${banklist[0].bank_account} "//This is printing in the log

            )

        }
    }
    )
    Log.d(
        "Data", "banksList2 ${banklist[0].bank_account} " //This is throwing null pointer exception

    )

    return banklist //this is null

  //if I return banklistLivedata it works perfectly and doesn't throw null
}
```

Comment: Can you add more information showing how you call this function and where the exception occurs along with the exception message you got. As it stands now, I can't reproduce the error you are getting

Comment: val list = list()

        if (list.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            Log.d("CashActivity", "List Null")
        } else {
            Log.d("CashActivity", "List ${list[0].bank_account}")
        } The log is printing null

Comment: That makes sense. [`isNullOrEmpty()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/is-null-or-empty.html) works with null lists and will return true if the list is either null or empty (just like the name says). So your list is indeed null as the current answer suggests and this is because it was never reached to be returned in the function call. When I say "it is null", I mean outside the function i.e. the receiver object that expects to get a list from this function is null

Comment: @smac89 thank you, so there is no solution?

Comment: The solution is simple: Check if your `banklist` (inside the function) has any data before attempting to log its first element (`Log.d("Data", "banksList1 ${banklist[0].bank_account} ")`)

Comment: @smac89 it has please read the first comment in this function, I have two logs the first is printing the value.

Comment: I can't reproduce what you are claiming. If you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://shorturl.at/DIOR0), then I can look into this further. The line you are saying doesn't cause any problems has a higher chance of success because the for-loop before it has possibly populated the list, so there is a chance it is not empty and therefore will not cause any exceptions to occur. However the last log is not at all guaranteed to run after the list has possibly been populated, so its chance of failure is higher. This is all speculation though until you provide more evidence

Answer (score 2):

The NPE thrown in your logging is because `banklist` is modified in a change listener.

```
Log.d(
        "Data", "banksList2 ${banklist[0].bank_account} " //This is throwing null pointer exception

    )
```

When no change was done, or inside the listener the iterable `dataSnapshot.children` is empty - `banklist` stays empty. So when you call *list[index]* it will return `null` since nothing was found and it will throw a NPE because you call `.bank_account` on `null`.

---

```
return banklist //this is null
```

I'm pretty sure that `banklist` at the end of your method is **not** null. The part is just never reached because the code before throws an Exception.

Comment: Just confirmed its null. I just called it and checked if it's empty and yes it's empty. I don't understand your comment since the list is in the same section as the log.

Comment: @coder254 You have to check if it is null outside the function, not from inside the function. It is null because the part was never reached as this answer states. So it wasn't returned.

Comment: I did so outside the function. I called the function from another function

Comment: @coder254 When the ValueEventListener is invoked, it has an old value/reference of `banklist` at the time you created it with `fun List()`. Outside the (listener) scope during this invocation, the `banklist` doesn't exist - so `null`.

Comment: @coder254 What do you want to return in your `fun List()`? As far as I can see, the `banklist` will always be empty. If you want to collect the values from every event, store the `banklist` as a field in a companion object. If you simply want to avoid NPEs, use @smac89 answer `firstOrNull`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to make sure that you are checking if the list is empty before attempting to log, or better yet use one of Kotlin's utility methods (like [**`firstOrNull()`**](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/first-or-null.html)) to retrieve the first element of the list:

```
Log.d("Data", "banksList2 ${banklist.firstOrNull()?.bank_account} ")
```

I'd also suggest doing the same for the logging inside the listener:

```
Log.d("Data", "banksList1 ${banklist.firstOrNull()?.bank_account} ")
```

Comment: Also if I use livedata I am getting the live data of the list. It returns it perfectly.